Constexpr for vector that contains a std::string compiler bug
I am really puzzled by the following code. Understand that this code DOES compile on Visual Studio 2022 C++ 20 (/std:c++20), version (17.10.6).  This question is not a duplicate of:  Why can I define a std::string instance that is constinit? Isn't constinit forbidden if an object requires dynamic initialization?
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

class AppData
{
    public:
        static inline const std::wstring APPLICATION_TITLE = L"Test\n";
        static inline constexpr std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, std::wstring>> APP_TITLE_FMT{ { 0, L"\x1b[1mHello" }, { 4, L"\x1b[0mHello" } };
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::wcout << AppData::APP_TITLE_FMT.at(0).second.c_str() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

To my understanding, a std::string can't be constexpr because of the fact that it's heap allocated and it can only be constexpr if it's destroyed during evaluation. However, I read that in C++ 20, they were going to make std::vector constexpr so I thought I'd try it.
Take the above code, the std::wstring obviously can't be constexpr, unless you made it an array, but I specifically needed a string. The second line it's a vector of pairs, where one of types of the pair is a wstring. So how can this be constexpr?  Someone suggested this maybe SSO.
Now I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (17.10.6), so this might be a Microsoft compiler bug, but the Intellisense says, nope, but the compiler says, yup and that it's perfectly fine and compiles without errors or warnings.
Just to be clear, I haven't tried this in Godbolt, so maybe it works there, maybe it doesn't... But this code DOES compile completely properly on Visual Studio 2022 with C++ 20.
Is this an actual compiler bug?
UPDATE
I have tested this bug with really long strings to see if it's some sort of SSO and it STILL compiles perfectly well with long strings (60+ chars).
My version of Visual Studio is :
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.11.5
And my cl version is:
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34123 for x64

The bug has been fixed in a later version of MSVC so now it doesn't compile anymore. I have 17.11.0 Preview 6.0 and it refuses. I'll upgrade to 17.12.0 Preview 2.1 to see if it still refuses.

@RichardCritten It doesn't matter what size of string you use, so this isn't a SSO issue.  I've tried it with longer strings and it still compiles perfectly well.

I'm getting error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant with cl.exe 19.41.33923.

@Eljay Yeah, cl.exe 19.41 is from a newer VS than 17.10 I suspect. VS 17.10 accepts it while VS 17.11 don't.

@TheWelder VS 17.12.0 Preview 2.1 (cl.exe 19.42.34321.1) won't accept the program either, so upgrade your Visual Studio.

@Eljay Well,. I've just updated Visual Studio to the latest downloadable version using the Visual Studio Installer to:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.11.5
And the above code STILL compiles perfectly without errors or warnings.

What is the version of cl.exe that came with MSVS 17.11.5?

As already said in the  Old deleteed question see the SSO dupe Why can I define a std::string instance that is constinit? Isn't constinit forbidden if an object requires dynamic initialization?

@user12002570 No, SSO was already ruled out.

@TedLyngmo No it was not ruled out anywhere in the deleted question. I see one comment by OP here that says they tried it with longer string and still get the same thing so this will rule out SSO. This should be in the main question instead of comment though.

@TheWelder user12002570 makes a good point. Make the code in the question use a string long enough to rule out SSO.

@TheWelder ... and Eljay also asked an interesting question. What version of cl.exe do you have?

@TedLyngmo I have tested this bug with really long strings to see if it's some sort of SSO and it STILL compiles perfectly well with long strings (60+ chars).  My version of Visual Studio is : Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.11.5
And my cl version is:  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34123 for x64

@TheWelder Yeah, I know that you did and I did too with the same result, but in order for other people to not come in and close the question for being a duplicate of a Q where the answer was SSO, you could put long strings in your question.


Is this an actual compiler bug?

Yes, but it has been fixed and several releases have been made since VS 17.10 so upgrade your Visual Studio 2022 and it will give you the expected error for the line
static inline constexpr std::vector<std::pair<uint32_t, std::wstring>> APP_TITLE_FMT{ { 0, L"\x1b[1mHello" }, { 4, L"\x1b[0mHello" } };

error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

(sub-)object points to memory which was heap allocated during constant evaluation


Thanks for the advice and like I've said in my previous comment, I've just updated Visual Studio to the latest version available through updates (v17.11.5) and the bug is still present as the code compiles without warnings or errors.

@TheWelder The latest is 17.12.0 but even 17.11.0 worked properly. You installation may be corrupt and you may need to reinstall it from scratch.

The latest version downloadable through Visual Studio update/Installer is the version I have. which is v17.11.5.  Versions beyond this may be available as a fresh install perhaps, like v17.12.0, but I don't have time to re-install Visual Studio and set it all up again.  I doubt it is a corrupt installation, as it would be a VERY specific and lucky type of corruption to somehow allow this to compile.

@TheWelder That's not the type of corruption I'm worried about. In cases where many installations co-exist some config mishap could make it select the wrong compiler. It's also possible that the Enterprise version mumbers differs from the community ones but that's unlikely.

Yeah I get that and I was concerned about this too. I don't have another installations of Visual Studio 2022 on this machine, but there are quite a few cl.exe compilers from what I can see.  Do you know of a way to build a project so that it dumps the version of cl.exe and link that's being used?  Like you, I want to figure out what's actually being used when you F7 this code.  It's really quite interesting.

@TheWelder Hmm... I don't have VS in front of me right now, but check if /nologo is enabled when you compile. If it is, remove that and it should show the version.

Yup, I have already done this before you suggested it and found something interesting. The code compiles with this:
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64>cl.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.36.32546 for x86
Two things jump out at me... Why is it is x86 compiler but in Hostx64?  Secondly, why it is using that compiler when: c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64\x64>cl.exe
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.41.34123 for x64
Is available?

@TheWelder It does sound like a configuration problem to me. I'm not that in to how MSVC does things, but, using the versions we've explicitly pointed out, I can make it "no" or "yes".  What's clear is: It is a bug - it is fixed. You don't have the fix available to you just yet.

I accept it is a bug in the version that my Visual Studio is using. I know it's now been fixed and that I've got some kind of configuration issue where VS is picking the wrong folder for the toolset. My toolset is set to v143, but it's not using the latest tools from MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\Hostx64, it's using the tools from MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\Hostx64 and I've got to try and figure out why and how to change it to use the correct folder for the v143 toolset.  If you suddenly think of something to change, please let me know!

@TheWelder At this point, the only thing that can change is in your dev. environment. The same setup works for others, so in this case, I'd explore the possibility that there is something different in your setup.

I ran the Visual Studio Installer, selected all the toolsets that I needed and let it run.  Now everything is fixed and it's using the right folder of tools for v143.  So, thanks for all your help man, it's appreciated.  I don't know why or how the configuration was screwed up, but seems resolved now.  Ironically, I didn't really care about this bug as it wasn't really an issue for me anyway, as usually I'd have used const rather than constexpr, but wanted to ask and help anyone else that may experience this weirdness.  Thanks once again.

@TheWelder Great!  Even though the underlying reason is still obscured by something that some wizard or other tool did a long time ago, it's at least nice to get the environment in a state where you can trust that it'll do what the version number promises it will do. I'm really glad it worked out!
